# PDI Mongo Input Parameter

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, pdi

I'm using two transformations and one job. My first transform gets two fields and I attempt to pass those fields in my job down to my second transform - in my mongo input, query step

```
{
  dataObjectId: ${idddddddddd}

}
```

when that step runs I NEVER get the param dynamically inserted but I do get TWO entires in the logs so it knows to only issue the command twice its just not taking the value!

```
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{
  dataObjectId: 

}
                    ^

{
  dataObjectId: 

}
                    ^

    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.mongodbinput.MongoDbInput.processRow(MongoDbInput.java:137)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:821)
Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException:
```

Here's my job's second transform params: 
[image]

which I'm sure is how the transform knows to only issue the mongo query twice but WHY isn't the param value coming through?